# Broken image from MapServer, PNG not rendering

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, postgresql, mapserver

I'm trying to render WMS MapServer data on top of Google Maps using the OpenLayers JS library. My problem arises when I try to render the data as a series of points throughout the New York City area. On my local machine I get a broken image, but on my live server I get no broken PNG data or anything at all.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

You can also check out the live site at: `http://134.74.146.40/~Oviedo12/final/subway%20crowding/view.html`.

OpenLayers JavaScript code below:

```
var map;
var mapBounds      = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-8266100.0, 4938263.9, -8204223.4, 4999860.8);
var movementBounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-8266100.0, 4938263.9, -8204223.4, 5030000.0);
var aliasproj = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var options = {
        projection: "EPSG:4326",
        units: "ft",
        maxResolution: 'auto',
        restrictedExtent: movementBounds,
        maxExtent: mapBounds
    };

function init(){
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);
    var base_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                    'Google Streets', // the default
                    {   numZoomLevels: 20, 
                        projection: aliasproj, 
                        isBaseLayer: true
                    });

    //change 'Oviedo12' to your login name
    var wms_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("WMS Overlay",
        "mapscripts/dynamicwms.php", 
        {layers: 'L_line', transparent: true, format: 'image/png', reqType:'wms'},
        {isBaseLayer: false, visibility: true}
    );
    //*/

    map.addLayers([base_layer, wms_layer])
    //map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);
    map.zoomToExtent(map.maxExtent);
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({position: new OpenLayers.Pixel(0,0)}));
}
```

Map file code:

```
MAP
  IMAGETYPE      PNG
  STATUS         ON
  IMAGECOLOR     255 255 255  

  PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:4326"
  END

  SYMBOL
      NAME 'circle'
      TYPE ELLIPSE
      POINTS 1 1 END
      FILLED TRUE
  END

  OUTPUTFORMAT
    NAME png
    DRIVER "GD/PNG"
    MIMETYPE "image/png"
    IMAGEMODE RGB
    EXTENSION "png"
  END

  OUTPUTFORMAT
    NAME jpeg
    DRIVER "GD/JPEG"
    MIMETYPE "image/jpeg"
    IMAGEMODE RGB
    EXTENSION "jpg"
    FORMATOPTION QUALITY=80
  END

END # All map files must come to an end just as all other things must come to...
```

PHP code for dynamic render:

```
<?php

if (!extension_loaded("MapScript")) dl("php_mapscript.so");

$request = ms_newowsrequestobj();

foreach ($_GET as $k=>$v) {
     $request->setParameter($k, $v);
}

$request->setParameter("VeRsIoN","1.0.0");
ms_ioinstallstdouttobuffer();
$oMap = ms_newMapobj("../maps/dynamic.map");


$new_layer =ms_newlayerobj($oMap);
$new_layer->set("type", MS_LAYER_POINT);
$new_layer->set("dump", 1);
$new_layer->set("status", 1);
$new_layer->set("name","L_line");
$new_class = ms_newClassObj($new_layer);
$new_style = ms_newStyleObj($new_class);
$new_style-> color->setRGB(0, 0,255);
$new_style->set("symbolname", "circle");
$new_style->set("size", 5);

$new_layer->setConnectionType(MS_POSTGIS);
$new_layer->set("connection","stuff to connect to db");
$data="the_geom from (select the_geom from station2 where lines = 'Canarsie') as foo using unique the_geom using SRID=4326";
echo ;
$new_layer->set("data",$data) ;


$oMap->owsdispatch($request);
$contenttype = ms_iostripstdoutbuffercontenttype();
if ($contenttype == 'image/png')
{
   header('Content-type: image/png');
   ms_iogetStdoutBufferBytes();
}
else
{
    $buffer = ms_iogetstdoutbufferstring();
    echo $buffer;
}
ms_ioresethandlers();
?>
```

Comment: It looks like MapServer can't open your map file.  Warning: [MapServer Error]: msLoadMap(): First token must be MAP, this doesn't look like a mapfile. in /home/Oviedo12/public_html/final/subway crowding/mapscripts/dynamicwms.php on line 13

Warning: Failed to open map file ../maps/dynamic.map in /home/Oviedo12/public_html/final/subway crowding/mapscripts/dynamicwms.php on line 13

Fatal error: Object expected as argument. in /home/Oviedo12/public_html/final/subway crowding/mapscripts/dynamicwms.php on line 16  I would check permissions on that file.

Comment: I fixed that error and placed the correct mapfile file.

Comment: Your link to the live site doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `ms_iostripstdoutbuffercontenttype()` function, I think it's setting your `$contenttype` as text when it should be setting it as PNG. Also, Chrome is complaining that this link is 404'ing:

`http://134.74.146.40/~Oviedo12/final/subway%20crowding/js/theme/default/style.css`

edit: Also as Dave points out in the comment, set your map to a static path instead of a dynamic one and see if that helps.

edit x2: Change your `$oMap` in your php code from this:

`ms_newMapobj("../maps/dynamic.map");`

to this:

`ms_newMapobj("http://134.74.146.40/~Oviedo12/final/subway%20crowding/maps/dynamic.map");`

Comment: I finished fixing that error, I'm still getting a  Warning: [MapServer Error]: error.Warning: [MapServer Error]: msLoadMap(): (/home/Oviedo12/public_html/final/subway crowding/maps/maps/dynamic.map) in /home/Oviedo12/public_html/final/subway crowding/mapscripts/dynamicwms.php on line 13

Comment: Yeah, that's a bad link to your `dynamic.map` file, you've got one too many 'maps' in the path.

Comment: I saw that error a while ago, but to my knowledge I have no idea what it mean. I don't use any file of that name. I think it has something to so with twitter bootstrap, as that's what I'm using for my frontend.

Comment: See edit x2 in my answer above.

Comment: After the x2 edit I still get the same error: Warning: [MapServer Error]: msLoadMap(): (http://134.74.146.40/~Oviedo12/final/subway%20crowding/maps/dynamic.map) in /home/Oviedo12/public_html/final/subway crowding/mapscripts/dynamicwms.php on line 13................Also, if i change it back to ms_newMapobj("../maps/dynamic.map"); is "kinda works".

Comment: I see broken PNGs now! `https://dl.dropbox.com/u/68073286/img/broken_png.jpg`

Comment: How do you fix those?

Comment: Yes I saw those to, but the error message seems to be pointing to the mapfile. The dynamicwms.php file still receives a Fatal error: Object expected as argument. in /home/Oviedo12/public_html/final/subway crowding/mapscripts/dynamicwms.php on line 16

Comment: Looks like your `ms_iostripstdoutbuffercontenttype()` function is still assigning the wrong type, or you're mangling your PNGs on transfer somehow.

Comment: What's on line 16 in your php file?